# Dynamodb Autoscaling not working fast enough

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm running a simple api that gets an item from a dynamodb table on each call, I have auto scaling set to a minimum of 25 and a maximum of 10 000.

However if I send 15 000 requests with a tool like wrk or hey, I get about 1000 502s,

- dynamodb's metrics show that reads are throttled
- the scaling activities log on the table shows that the RCUs were scaled to 99 but not more than that
- lambda logs show that the function starts to take longer, it usually takes about 20ms to run, but the function starts to run for 500.1500,3000 ms and start timing out (I'm assuming that's caused by the throttling)

Why isn't the autoscaling working better? It only scales upto 99RCUs but my max is 10, 000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html

What you defined as "target utilization"?

> Target utilization is the ratio of consumed capacity units to provisioned capacity units, expressed as a percentage. Application Auto Scaling uses its target tracking algorithm to ensure that the provisioned read capacity of ProductCatalog is adjusted as required so that utilization remains at or near 70 percent.

also, i think that the main reason that autoscale not works for you, is because your work might not stay elevated for a long time:

"DynamoDB auto scaling modifies provisioned throughput settings only when the actual workload stays elevated (or depressed) for a sustained period of several minutes"

> DynamoDB auto scaling modifies provisioned throughput settings only when the actual workload stays elevated (or depressed) for a sustained period of several minutes. The Application Auto Scaling target tracking algorithm seeks to keep the target utilization at or near your chosen value over the long term.
>   Sudden, short-duration spikes of activity are accommodated by the table's built-in burst capacity. For more information, see Use Burst Capacity Sparingly.

Comment: My target utilization is 70%, thanks for the link, the traffic is sustained for about a minute or two, which would explain this. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan also note that you want to use a bit of caution if you scale a DynamoDB table over such a wide range,  because when it scales up, it will split your partitions (giving you more of them), and when it scales back down, the partitions do not merge back together, and the provisioned throughput will be divided among all of the partitions.  If it splits to 4 partitions at 10K RCU, you'll still have 4 partitions at 25 RCU, which means only ~6 RCU per partition.  The minimum partition count at 10K RCU is 4, but it might be higher, and this value is not visible to you.

Answer (score 11):

We ran into the same problem when testing DynamoDB autoscaling for short amounts of time, and it turns out the problem is that the scaling events only happen after 5 minutes of elevated throughput (you can see this by inspecting the CloudWatch alarms the autoscaling sets up)

This excellent blog post helped us solve this by creating a Lambda that responds to the CloudWatch API events and improves the responsiveness of the alarms to one minute: https://hackernoon.com/the-problems-with-dynamodb-auto-scaling-and-how-it-might-be-improved-a92029c8c10b